# (duplicate) redirect from specific url / url detection

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, redirect

This question was too long and dumb, sorry to waste your time.

I was very new to programming and what this question was supposed to say is "how do I get a GET parameter using javascript?"

Sorry for the inconvienience.

Comment: use `window.location` and do your conditions

Comment: Don't expect help as you've shown no attempt in your question, please post some code, any attempts.

Comment: the code is very long and doesnt fit in the post

Comment: The best thing to do in that case @Sam is to show snippets of the code that relates to your question.

Comment: Take a look at this Guide: [ask]  to learn about how to ask good questions on stackoverflow in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is in PHP to read the `$_GET` variables of the request. This is an array corresponding to the values passed in the URL's querystring (e.g. `http://www.example.com/users.php?uname=pie&value2=X` would create two GET variables called "uname" and "value2". The value of `$_GET["uname"]` would be "pie" in your example.) Then you can use the value from the GET variable to fetch the correct data for the user.

See also http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

P.S. I don't think you want one *page* per user - that's very inflexible and requires too much maintenance. Instead use a database with a table of users, and use the same PHP page to display their data. Just use the "uname" value as parameter to pass to the database in order to return the data relevant to that user, and then use variables to place that data on the page correctly.

You can find hundreds of tutorials online which demonstrate how to use PHP and a free database such as MySQL to store and retrieve data in the way I'm describing.

Comment: Well you can't just paste exactly what I've written. You'd need to build some code to access the database etc, and pass the value of "uname" to the query as a parameter. But basically, if you have a page called, for example, "users.php" which displays this food intolerance data, then the first thing you would do in the PHP script you would need to check that the "uname" parameter exists and is valid, pass it to a database query, fetch the results and then display the resulting data.

Comment: I can't really be more specific because you haven't shown any relevant code of your own, or mentioned how you've designed this already except in quite vague terms. I've made a suggestion to use a database, but coding all that for you explicitly is too broad a question for SO and in any case you can google hundreds of generic examples of the process. I suggest you attempt it and then ask a more focused question, including the code you've written, if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Use `window.location` to redirect to  the file  /patients/XXXX.html: By access the GET parameter 'uname'  and concatenating it together  using  `+`

```js
window.location.href = "/patients/" + findGetParameter("uname") + ".html";

function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
  var result = null,
    tmp = [];
  var items = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
  for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    tmp = items[index].split("=");
    if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now just make a folder called "patients" and a bunch of files called "Johnson.html",  "Roberts.html", etc, etc. in the patients folder and they will be redirected.

Comment: Just create a new `<script>` tag, paste the code, and then end it with `</script>` on the index page...